# WPF ComboBox DataBinding vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, combobox

I am trying to populate a combobox using databinding.Below are the snippets of my code.

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbClientName" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=blClientList}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=blClientList}"/>
```

**Code behind 'MainWindow':**

```
  Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

  Dim blClientList As ObservableCollection(Of String) = New ObservableCollection(Of String)
  Dim objClientRepository As PET_ClientRepository = New PET_ClientRepository

  For Each objClient As PET_Client In objClientRepository.GetAll()

     blClientList.Add(objClient.Name)
  Next

     Me.cmbClientName.ItemsSource = blClientList
  End Sub
```

**Class1.vb:**

```
Public Property Name As String
    Get
        Return _Name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _Name = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I would like to see the name of the client in my combobox. The code above does not return anything and combobox is blank.I know the problem lies in binding but can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: you shouldn't need the binding if you're going to set the itemssource in MainWindow_Loaded -- I wonder if that is interfering. And you're sure blClientList has entries when you set it the itemssource?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am new to WPF as well as VB so pardon my ignorance.Yes, "blClientList" has 10 entries. If I don't need binding then what are my other options? I would like the combobox to be loaded as soon as the application has started hence I put that in MainWindow_Loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help.

I went ahead with populating the combobox in the code behind in stead of binding it to a datasource. I didn't even have to pass "ItemSource" in  XAML. I did however pass ItemSource in Mainwindow.vb which did the trick for me.

Below are the snippets of code that are working:

**Code behind MainWindow.vb**

```
Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

    Me.Username.Text = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name

    Dim blClientList As ObservableCollection(Of String) = New ObservableCollection(Of String)
    Dim objClientRepository As PET_ClientRepository = New PET_ClientRepository

    For Each objClient As PET_Client In objClientRepository.GetAll()

        blClientList.Add(objClient.Name)

    Next

    Me.cmbClientName.ItemsSource = blClientList
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbClientName" IsReadOnly="True" PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High"/>
```

Tracelevel isn't doing anything but is just there to provide debug tracing support.

**Class1.vb**

```
 Public Property Name As String
    Get
        Return _Name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _Name = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Question is about databinding.  But answer is not

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
Me.cmbClientName.ItemsSource = blClientList
```

with this:

```
Me.DataContext = blClientList
```

and correct XAML as:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbClientName" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          DisplayMemberPath="." SelectedValuePath="."/>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I tried that initially before asking the question but got no where.

Comment: @presarioruby See updated post. It is better to add the `PET_Client` to the collection and set the `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` to the appropriate properties.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried what you suggested but still no luck.

`<ComboBox Name="cmbClientName" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  DisplayMemberPath="." SelectedValuePath="."/> `

`Dim blClientList As ObservableCollection(Of PET_Client) = New ObservableCollection(Of PET_Client)`

Comment: Maybe your code is different from provided  because the above code is working one.

Comment: @presarioruby No, If you use the collection of `PET_Client` as datacontext you must use the navigation path as `DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Name"`. Instead of the `SelectedValuePath` you can set the unique identifier of your entity.

Comment: I tried both the ways as suggested by you and still no luck!

Comment: It is actually working code, perhaps,  you have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that may help you achieve your desired result:

Re: your comment, binding is good, you just need to set context

WPF

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4VB"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="293">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:Vm />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

important things being that you add your local namespace:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4VB"
```

and that you set DataContext

Classes

```
Public Class Vm
    Public Property Collection As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of Thing)
    Public Sub New()
        Collection = New ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of Thing)()
        Collection.Add(New Thing("Test1"))
        Collection.Add(New Thing("Test2"))
        Collection.Add(New Thing("Test3"))
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Thing
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Sub New(Name As String)
        Me.Name = Name
    End Sub
End Class
```